# Error in ridge.fit. 'unexpected keyword argument 'sym_pos' How do I solve this?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I was writing a code for the Ridge regression model to apply to Boston housing data, and I got an error in the code below.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

def load_data():
    X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
    feature_names = load_boston().feature_names
    return X,y,feature_names
    
def Ridge_regression(X, y):
    ridge_reg = Ridge(alpha= 10)
    ridge_reg.fit(X,y)
    return ridge_reg

def Lasso_regression(X, y):
    lasso_reg = Lasso(alpha= 10)
    lasso_reg.fit(X,y)
    return lasso_reg
    
def plot_graph(coef, title):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.ylim(-1,1)
    plt.title(title)
    coef.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.savefig("result.png")

def main():
    X,y,feature_names = load_data()
    ridge_reg = Ridge_regression(X, y)
    lasso_reg = Lasso_regression(X, y)
    ridge_coef = pd.Series(ridge_reg.coef_, feature_names).sort_values()
    print("Ridge  beta_i\n", ridge_coef)
    lasso_coef = pd.Series(lasso_reg.coef_, feature_names).sort_values()
    print("Lasso beta_i\n", lasso_coef)
    plot_graph(ridge_coef, 'Ridge')
    plot_graph(lasso_coef, 'Lasso')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The warning being:

```
File c:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_ridge.py:1011, in Ridge.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1002 _accept_sparse = _get_valid_accept_sparse(sparse.issparse(X), self.solver)
   1003 X, y = self._validate_data(
   1004     X,
   1005     y,
...
--> 157     return linalg.solve(A, Xy, sym_pos=True, overwrite_a=True).T
    158 else:
    159     coefs = np.empty([n_targets, n_features], dtype=X.dtype)

TypeError: solve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sym_pos'
```

I want to know how this code can work normally.

I have read a document about `Ridge.fit` but I have not been able to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you update `scikit-learn`, does the error go away?

Comment: ... https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/23617

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem was that I was using version 1.02 of scikit learn for using Boston housing data. I updated the version and called up the housing data using fetch_openml, and the code worked fine. Thanks once again.

Comment: With 1.3.1, I actually still have this problem